# Print binary tree in level order using only one extra pointer per node

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

Given a binary tree whose nodes have the following type:

```cpp
struct Node {
  Node* left;
  Node* right;
  int data;
  Node* foo;   // uninitialized - use it any way you like
};
```

Print the tree data in level order and leave the `foo` member of each node pointing to the next sibling node.

We are not allowed to use any other storage except a constant number of variables with non-array type (in particular, an external queue is not allowed).

Comment: So... Basically what you get is a linked list for each level.. which is just a set of queues if you so want. It's somewhat arbitrary to call this "not using  a queue"

Comment: @NiklasB. I tightened up the problem statement.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat IMO "next sibling node" isn't identical to "next node in that order". With the first interpretation, `foo`'s value for the last node in any given level would be left unspecified by the problem statement - the idea might be to have it be `NULL`, which isn't a trivial change.

Comment: @Dukeling I find this problem interesting and implemented a solution which seems to be working fine. But what would be your interpretation of next sibling here? I assumed next sibling to be the next node in that level, but it can be the next node that has the same parent. It's quite different. What do you say?

Comment: @Dukeling If you would be so kind to give a look at my answer, I would really appreciate some expert advice in case something's wrong ;)

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves next sibling refers to next node at the same level. they need not share the immediate parent

Comment: @Aadith Good - then see my answer. It was relatively well tested, I think it's what the interviewer was expecting.

Comment: Why did you clear out most of the problem statement?

Comment: Rolled back your edit as the way you edited it largely invalidates the answers - case and point would be "What is 'foo'?" and "Why are all the answers so complicated? Where's the simple BFS approach?".

Answer (score 6):

The idea is very simple - a queue can be represented as a linked-list, so use `foo` to indicate the next node in the linked-list, and just keep track of the last node for enqueuing.

Psuedo-code:

```java
current = root
lastNode = current
while current != null
   process current
   if current.left != null
      if lastNode != null
         lastNode.foo = current.left
      lastNode = lastNode.foo
   if current.right != null
      if lastNode != null
         lastNode.foo = current.right
      lastNode = lastNode.foo
   current = current.foo
```

For the sake of simplicity, I'm assuming all `foo`'s are initialized to `null`.
If this is not the case, just set `lastNode.foo = null` whenever `lastNode` changes.

If we want `foo` for the last node in any given level to be `null` rather than point to the first node in the next level (which might be part of the requirements - it's a bit unclear), we could fairly easily keep track of the first node of the next level, and set `current.foo` to `null` when it's pointing to that node.

The key to the correctness of this is that there will never be more than one level in the tree, thus `firstNextLevel` can't skip a level, and will only get set when we're at the start of a level.

```java
current = root
lastNode = current
firstNextLevel = null

while current != null
   process current

   if current.left != null
      if lastNode != null
         lastNode.foo = current.left
      lastNode = lastNode.foo
      if firstNextLevel == null
         firstNextLevel = lastNode

   if current.right != null
      if lastNode != null
         lastNode.foo = current.right
      lastNode = lastNode.foo
      if firstNextLevel == null
         firstNextLevel = lastNode

   if current.foo == firstNextLevel
      temp = current
      current = current.foo
      temp.foo = null
      firstNextLevel = null
   else
      current = current.foo
```

---

And then a hopelessly overcomplicated solution involving having `foo` point to the next node in the same level only.

We just need to set up the next level's `foo`'s when traversing this level, and keep track of the first node in the next level so we know where to carry on from when done with this level.

The pseudo-code will look something like:

```java
current = root
firstInNextLevel = null
prevInNextLevel = null
while current != null
   // this loop can happen twice for current, so we need this check
   if prevInNextLevel != current.left
      process current

   // pick left first, then right, then nothing
   if current.left != null && prevInNextLevel != current.left
                           && prevInNextLevel != current.right
      currentInNextLevel = current.left
   else if current.right != null && prevInNextLevel != current.right
      currentInNextLevel = current.right
   else
      currentInNextLevel = null

   if currentInNextLevel != null
      // set up foo for previous node
      if prevInNextLevel != null
         prevInNextLevel.foo = currentInNextLevel
      else
         firstInNextLevel = currentInNextLevel
      prevInNextLevel = currentInNextLevel
   else
      // done with current, move on
      current = current.foo
      // no nodes left on this level, move on to the next
      if current == null
         if prevInNextLevel != null
            prevInNextLevel.foo = null
         current = firstInNextLevel
         firstInNextLevel = null
         prevInNextLevel = null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point is how to use the pointer foo. For the leftmost child, you can use this pointer to point to the sibling node in the right side, then what about the rightmost child? I think you can use it to point to the node in the right side although it is not his sibling. Let me use example to show my idea:

A tree

> ```
> 1
> ```
>
> 3    5
>
> 2  nil   4  7

We can put a "empty node" between node 2 and node 4 (no values but with pointers, including foo). Make foo of node 2 point to it. And make its foo point to node 4. If we have this structure, Then when we serialize this tree, we just need to record the leftmost node of this level and output all nodes of this level into file. Then start to traverse next level from the left child of the node we record. The foo pointer can help us go through whole level. (The rightmost node has foo point to null)

By using this way, for the example above, we can get following file (one line one level)

> `1`
>
> 3 5
>
> 2 # 4 7

When we do deserialize, we just go through file and create tree. The key part is connect node '#' with node '4'.

Comment: That's a little bit of cheating though - I'd assume that the interviewer wouldn't allow you to allocate new nodes. And how would you allocate it? With `malloc`? What if the tree you're given is not in dynamic memory? You'd be inserting hard-to-track memory leaks, and it would be extremely hard to fix them. And how would you differentiate these special nodes from regular nodes? Regular nodes can have any value in `data`, and they can have no children - there is nothing in the structure that allows you to do such differentiation.

Comment: Beyond Filipe's concerns - how will you get this new node to point to 4 (in your example) - that's non-trivial. And serializing the tree would presumably be considered cheating too.

Comment: I think the question changed. Initially, the question is about how to use foo sibling pointer to complete task of breadth-first traverse without using queues. So for questions mentioned in above comments, <1 - for Filipe> I am trying to design a new structure with foo pointer, not change current structure. If current structure is fixed, I think you don't need my solution. <2 - for Dukeling> In fact, when you try to print tree, you are doing serialization. Anyway, I still didn't understand why this solution becomes cheating. still, the question changed and was edited.

Comment: I think my issue is trying to assume the tree has some kind of good structure as what I need (I was thinking this is a question to ask you design tree structure). Anyway, the solution of Dukeling is good.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, Dukeling touched the key point here. The idea is to use `foo` as a "next" pointer in a linked list. Each level in the tree is thus seen as a linked list of nodes.

My code goes through the tree, level by level, it sets the correct values for `foo` pointers in the next level, so that a linked list is properly formed. At the same time, it prints the values for the current level.

**Note:** I assume that by sibling you mean the next node in that level. If you mean the other node that has the same parent, then it's a little bit trickier and it will require deep changes.

```
void print_bfs_aux(struct Node *);

void print_bfs(struct Node *root) {
  root->foo = NULL;
  print_bfs_aux(root);
}

void print_bfs_aux(struct Node *root) {

  if (!root)
    return;

  struct Node *next_level = NULL;
  struct Node *prev = NULL;

  for (struct Node *current = root; current != NULL; current = current->foo) {

    printf("\t%d", current->data);

    struct Node *new_prev = NULL;

    if (current->left) {
      new_prev = current->left;
    } else if (current->right) {
      new_prev = current->right;
    } else {
      new_prev = prev;
    }

    if (prev && new_prev != prev)
      prev->foo = new_prev;

    if (current->left && current->right) {
      /* assert: new_prev = current->left */
      current->left->foo = current->right;
      new_prev = current->right;
    }

    prev = new_prev;

    if (!next_level) {
      if (current->left)
    next_level = current->left;
      else if (current->right)
    next_level = current->right;
    }

  }

  if (prev)
    prev->foo = NULL;

  printf("\n");

  print_bfs_aux(next_level);

}
```

At each iteration, `prev` points to the node that is currently the last node in the linked list being built for the next level, and `current` is the node we are visiting (and printing) from the current level. `next_level` is the head of the list for the next level. The idea is not very complex, but the code is subtle because it needs to deal gracefully with arbitrarily unbalanced trees.

The client code should call `print_bfs()`, that's the entry point where the root's `foo` is initialized. The code does not assume that `foo`'s are initialized to `NULL`. It also (hopefully) works for any kind of unbalanced tree, as well as perfectly balanced trees. It is just a matter of being careful not to mess it up when constructing the linked list for the next level.

By the way, if you want to quickly test this, here's what I've used:

```
int main(void) {

  struct Node nodes[100];

  int node, left, right;

  while (scanf("%d %d %d", &node, &left, &right) == 3) {
    if (left == -1)
      nodes[node].left = NULL;
    else
      nodes[node].left = &nodes[left];
    if (right == -1)
      nodes[node].right = NULL;
    else
      nodes[node].right = &nodes[right];
    nodes[node].data = node;
  }

  print_bfs(&nodes[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Some word of advice though: if your interviewer further asked you to develop some testing routines, don't make code like that; it was just a quick dirty way to perform some basic testing.

Some input tests you might want to try:

```
/* Input for test 1 */
0 1 2
1 -1 4
2 5 6
4 10 11
5 12 13 
6 14 15
10 -1 -1
11 -1 -1
12 -1 -1
13 -1 -1
14 -1 -1
15 -1 -1

/* A fully balanced tree */
0 1 2
1 3 4
2 5 6
3 8 9
4 10 11
5 12 13
6 14 15
8 -1 -1
9 -1 -1 
10 -1 -1
11 -1 -1
12 -1 -1
13 -1 -1
14 -1 -1
15 -1 -1

/* An unbalanced tree */
0 1 2
1 -1 -1
2 5 -1
5 12 13
12 -1 -1
13 -1 -1

/* Something a little bit longer */
0 1 2
1 3 -1
2 5 6
3 8 9 
5 12 13
6 14 15
8 -1 -1
9 -1 -1
12 -1 -1
13 -1 -1
14 -1 -1
15 16 -1
16 17 -1
17 18 -1
18 -1 19
19 -1 20
20 -1 -1
```